# get info from third table with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Service model. every service can be given by several users, so I have a User model.

I have a connection table: services_users with a ServiceUser model

p.s: this table has user_id, service_id and blah_id columns

Now, I want to write: service.users and get all users from users table for a given service.

How would I write this in the model?
service.users gives me a query from services_users, which is the connecting table, but I want the results from users table.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `has_and_belongs_to_many` association to facilitate.

**service.rb**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

**user.rb**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
```

and now you can simply:

```
your_service.users
```

Comment: The connecting table is named: families_users, which is not rails default for how I described in my question,so how would you write this?

Comment: You didn't describe it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ServiceUser` model. you need `User` and `Service` model with `has_and_belongs_to_many` association on both the models and the connecting table. Then you can access `users` by `service.users`. [HABTM association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)